# Output JSON Array from Azure function and app service being split up into individual messages

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-eventhub

I have an azure function and an azure app-service that are both exhibiting the same behaviour. From both I output a payload containing a Json array with several Json Objects [{"x": "y"}, {"a": "b"}] in it to an eventhub. When I examine the eventhubs I see that the array has been split into the individual constituent Json Objects.

{"x": "y"}

and

{"a": "b"}

(i.e. 2 messages)

I cannot find documentation of this anywhere and do not know if it is a feature of the app runtime, client libs or the event hub itself.

I would like to be able to control this behaviour. The only way I found around it is to wrap the array in a Json object something like this:

{"payload": [{"x": "y"}, {"a": "b"}]}

Edit 1:
The function is written in java with spring cloud function. Here is the definition of the Handler including the bindings:

```
public class CollectMessageHandler extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<Message, String> {
    @FunctionName("collect")
    @EventHubOutput(name = "output", eventHubName = "collected", connection = "OUT_CONN_STRING")
    public String collect(
            @EventHubTrigger(name = "input", eventHubName = "incoming", cardinality = Cardinality.ONE, connection = "IN_CONN_STRING") Message message,
            ExecutionContext targetExecutionContext
    ) {
        return handleRequest(message, targetExecutionContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your function code with bindings?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I added the handler definition including bindings in edit 1 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this problem, after change multiple `dataType` and return type it still resolve the array to multiple json object. So I suppose the java Azure function will do that in default.

So after this my solution is put this json array into another array like below code.

```
public void run(
             @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context,
             @EventHubOutput(name = "event", eventHubName = "test", connection = "AzureEventHubConnection",dataType = "String") OutputBinding<Object> output) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
        jo1.put("firstName", "John");
        jo1.put("lastName", "Doe");
        JSONObject jo2 = new JSONObject();
        jo2.put("firstName", "george");
        jo2.put("lastName", "chen");


        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        ja.add(jo1);
        ja.add(jo2);


        Object[] o=new Object[]{ja};
        output.setValue(o);

    }
```

Then in the event it will show as an array like below pic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks George. Yeah that's similar to how I solved it: instead of wrapping in another array, I wrap it in a Json Object. My question was more around if it is documented and / or configurable.

Comment: I check the java function doc, it only says `To send multiple output values, use OutputBinding<T> defined in the azure-functions-java-library package` , if check the `azure-functions-java-library`  **OutputBinding** interface there is no much useful information. So if want to know much more information, maybe have to post an issue to github or other platforms to get help from the product group.